# Finding guitar picks in an image

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

[Starting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGMGV.jpg)
I have tried everything in the book to get this script to accurately find 14 guitar picks in this image.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
# Load image using PIL
image = Image.open("guitar_picks.jpeg")

# Convert PIL image to OpenCV format
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Preprocess image for contrast
clip_limit = 2.0
tile_size = (8,8)
while True:
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization (CLAHE) to grayscale image
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=clip_limit, tileGridSize=tile_size)
    img_clahe = clahe.apply(gray)

    # Apply noise reduction
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_clahe, (5, 5), 0)

    # Perform image segmentation
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
    cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2_imshow(thresh)
    # Detect circles in the thresholded image
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=5, maxRadius=30)

    # If circles are detected, draw them on the original image
    if circles is not None:
      circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
      for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)


    # Filter contours by size to eliminate noise and non-pick objects
    filtered_cnts = []
    for c in cnts:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        area = w * h
        if area > 500 and area < 5000:
            filtered_cnts.append(c)

    # Update number of picks found
    num_picks = len(filtered_cnts)

    # Draw contours on original image
    for c in filtered_cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # Display the results
    cv2_imshow(img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Check if 14 guitar picks are found
    if num_picks == 14:
        print("14 guitar picks found!")
        # Save the image of highlighted guitar picks
        img_highlighted = img.copy()
        for c in filtered_cnts:
         cv2.drawContours(img_highlighted, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
         cv2.imwrite("highlighted_guitar_picks.jpeg", img_highlighted)
         finale = Image.open("highlighted_guitar_picks.jpeg")
        break

    # If fewer than 14 picks are found, adjust the contrast and try again
    elif num_picks < 14:
        # Increase the clip limit for the Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization (CLAHE)
        clip_limit += 0.5
        print(f"Trying new clip limit: {clip_limit}")
        if clip_limit > 5.0:
            print("Could not find 14 guitar picks with current settings.")
            break

    # If more than 14 picks are found, reduce the clip limit and try again
    else:
        # Decrease the clip limit for the Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization (CLAHE)
        clip_limit -= 0.5
        print(f"Trying new clip limit: {clip_limit}")
        if clip_limit < 0.5:
            print("Could not find 14 guitar picks with current settings.")
            break

# Destroy all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It is automated to change contrast values and it uses a variety of OpenCV components to do this. Thing is, the code works to find 14 guitar picks, but, it doesn't find the right ones. Instead, I end up getting an output result that looks like this:[Output Result of the 14 found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUK1d.jpg)

Even when printing the threshold image inline it is very... grainy. I have tried to denoise it but it doesn't work. I have spent 5 days on this and it has racked my brain.
How can I single out the exact 14 guitar picks?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do and achieve, I'd strongly suggest you rethink your image acquisition stage.

Comment: @stateMachine this is supposed to be a challenge for me but I really want to understand what is wrong with the code. I know there are easier images and I have attempted to utilize various versions of my code on them and the code works. Thanks for the suggestion though!